# Populate mysql table with random data in python

Tags: python, mysql, database

How can create a mysql table in python and then populate it with random data.I want around 10000 rows and integer values will do work.

Comment: what kind of data, how many rows?

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: ya i want around 10000 rows and any integer numbers will do work...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear (want to generate a table in python AND fill it with random data?).

Well, if you want to do it by hand, generate the random number using `random`. [Check it out!](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) Do a mini-logic with a cycle to [fill your rows](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm) (if you don't know how, search in this forum or ask.).

Also, check here (I haven't used it!): **[psyert](http://andreinc.net/2011/08/21/generate-random-sql-inserts-using-pysert-v0-1/)**

**Mini-note**: your questions have been **systematically downrated**. Please, check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) of StackOverflow and see how to do a proper elegant question. If English is not your native language, don't worry, but at least use the punctuation and get help from an online translator.